# How do I prevent the default behavior of the touchmove event in iOS 5?

Tags: javascript, ios5, dom-events, preventdefault

I have a web-based application that includes a component that the user can scroll up and down with their finger. I use the event's `preventDefault` method to prevent the default behavior where the touch move shifts the whole screen around on iOS devices.

Unfortunately this does not seem to work anymore in iOS 5 which I just upgraded to this morning. I have to assume that this is just done differently in iOS 5, but I have yet to be able to find a resource that provides instructions.

Update #1: I haven't been able to find an answer to my specific question, but I was able adjust my code a bit to use the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` style (set to a value of "touch") and implement the snazzy inertial scrolling capability (where the content scrolls faster depending on the velocity of your swipe and will "rubber band bounce" back if it hits the boundaries. Pretty cool looking...

Update #2: I have another strange problem now. For some odd reason that overflow scrolling behavior gets mixed up sometimes whereby you have to drag your finger left and right across the containing element in order to make its contents move up and down. I have yet to be able to figure out why this happens - does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

I found a very simple solution. When the event hits your element that is allowed to scroll, just flag the event. On the event listener on the document just check if the flag is set and only stop the event if the flag isn't set:

```
this.$scrollableEl.on('touchmove', function(event){
  event.comesFromScrollable = true;
  // when you have containers that are srollable but 
  // doesn't have enough content to scroll sometimes:
  // event.comesFromScrollable = el.offsetHeight < el.scrollHeight;
});

$(document).on('touchmove', function(event){
    if (!event.comesFromScrollable){
      event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You could also use [event.stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopImmediatePropagation) instead, so you dont need the eventListener on the document element, but this breaks zepto.js `tap` in my case:

```
this.$scrollableEl.on('touchmove', function(event){
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! I modified it the way that I just add a custom data- attribute and if thats available scrolling will not be stopped. this way we can save one eventlistener :)

Answer (score 6):

First, I can verify that e.preventDefault() disables all scrolling in iOS 5 using the following code:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }
```

Unfortunately, however, this disables the scrolling on overflow:scroll divs. (If anyone has a solution that leaves the inner element scrolling enabled, please share.)

Regarding update#2, I have noticed strange behavior when there is a scrollable element nested in another scrollable element (including the page itself). Sometimes the device hesitates on which element the user intends to scroll. In particular I've noticed this problem using position:fixed. My solution was to make sure the body has 100% height and that the scrollable elements use position:absolute where possible.

Comment: Maybe you could do some logic checking like `if($(e.currentTarget).css('overflow') != 'scroll') e.preventDefault();`.  Since document.ontouchmove will fire after the scollable element's ontouchmove, you could do `el.ontouchmove = function() {allowScroll = true}` and then have `document.ontouchmove` use that value to determine the action and then set the value back to false.

Comment: @BrianNickel Thanks for the tip. This is a step in the right direction that will allow you to prevent direct scrolling on an element-by-element basis (including directly scrolling on the body), but if the user touchmoves a scrollable element that is already at the edge of its scrollable range, it will still end up scrolling the body (showing the gray linen underneath). Perhaps the only way is to interpret the direction of the touchmove and check if the element is at the edge of its scrollable range?

Comment: @RyanRapp Thanks for your response. I perhaps didn't describe clearly enough what behavior I'm talking about. With iOS 4 I would use e.preventDefault() within an element (say, a DIV) with overflow's touchmove event handler such that I could shift the contents around via absolute positioning based on the movement of the finger within the element. Now the e.preventDefault() blocks this when I try to move my finger the entire page, which doesn't have enough content to scroll, doesn't so much scroll but moves around so that you can see Safari's background texture behind it.

Comment: This solution helped me a lot with my web based application.
Cheers!